# How do I structure a node.js project with a core and multiple, at the moment unknown extensions?

Tags: node.js

I have a project as core with a basic server. I want to have additional functionality in different projects which are used by this server. The server itself should not need to know each possible extension but find them if they are installed.

For the production system I want the user to be able to install the core package with one or multiple extensions as needed per use case.

Do anybody has an example how to structure this?
How does the core package know which extensions are installed?

Answer (score 0):

There's no set way of doing this, but the core package needs a way to "detect" which extensions are intended to be run and where they are.  Here are some of the various techniques:

1. A configuration file in a known location (often in your program directory, but could also be in a fixed location elsewhere on the drive) contains a list of the extension directories or initialization script paths and your core code loads this list from the configuration file and then loads each extension based on the information in that list.
2. There's a known directory (such as "extensions") in a known location relative to your program directory and your core code scans that extensions directory and loads any extensions it finds there.
3. You could use a combination of the two.  There could both be a known location for the extensions and a config file that specifies which extensions in that known location should be run.

For installation, since you want extensions to be "unknown" by the core, you could install the core and then have the user select which extensions they also want to install one at a time and have their installation process do whatever is required in the above steps (depending upon which method you use) to make them part of the configuration that runs.